# add sorting images in gridview header

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, sorting, gridview

I am adding 2 images of sorting;asc and desc in gridview header. But because the header in some columns is long/wrapped, the images get down and the whole structure looks bad.

Isn't there some way that the images stay at a good place irrespective of header text in grid view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to try.

I assume you are using the up/down arrow images followed by the header description. The description span/div should have a css style. Set the width of it to cover the maximum you can, but this will still break when there is a single word thats longer than that width. For such scenarios, use a css style `word-break: break-all;`. This will break the word even if there is no space in it. Also, is the header text dynamic? There is no one fix for it. You have to adjust your css to work around this.

One other thing I can think of is set position to relative on the container div and absolute on the images using css.

Comment: can you not increase the width of that column to adjust for the header?